# Featured image in CPT overview column

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm trying to remove the title and date in all my CPTs posts overview page and instead show a featured image. I have the below code working but what i do not know is if it's the correct way to do it and how to make it work only on my CPTs and not all posts

```
 //Remove title and date columns in CPT overview and instead show just thumbnail

    function jam_cpt_columns($columns) {

        unset(
            $columns['title'],
            $columns['date']
        );
        $new_columns = array(
            'featured_thumb' => 'Thumbnail',
        );
        return array_merge($columns, $new_columns);
    }
    add_filter('jam_manage_posts_custom_column' , 'jam_cpt_columns');

    function jam_cpt_columns_data( $column, $post_id ) {
        switch ( $column ) {
        case 'featured_thumb':
            echo '<a href="' . get_edit_post_link() . '">';
            echo the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );
            echo '</a>';
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
        add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns' , 'jam_cpt_columns' );
        add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column' , 'jam_cpt_columns_data', 10, 2 );
        add_filter( 'manage_pages_columns' , 'jam_cpt_columns' );
        add_action( 'manage_pages_custom_column' , 'jam_cpt_columns_data', 10, 2 );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like working. The post type slug is passed as a GET variable so if you want to add the code to specific post types, you can first grab the post type slug by:

```
if( isset($_GET['post_type']) ) {
    $post_type = $_GET['post_type'];

    if( in_array( $post_type, array('type1', 'type2', ...) ) ) {
        add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns' , 'jam_cpt_columns' );
        add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column' , 'jam_cpt_columns_data', 10, 2 );
        add_filter( 'manage_pages_columns' , 'jam_cpt_columns' );
        add_action( 'manage_pages_custom_column' , 'jam_cpt_columns_data', 10, 2 );
    }
}
```

you can specify your desired post types in the array.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and for enlightening me in the process. Much appreciated !